# Square root of two

Tags: geometry, radicals

How would you find root 2? I have been told to use a number line. I have tried to visualize it on a number line using triangles. But am unsure of where to go from there.

Comment: What do you mean my "find the square root of 2"? With a question that vague, I am really tempted to say that you should use a number line from $\sqrt{2}$ to $\sqrt{2}$ and you should point to it XD In all seriousness though, I can assist if you can clarify a bit further.

Comment: Do you want to find the decimal expansion of it (i.e. $1.41421\dots$)?

Comment: Here is [Square root 2 in something else](https://geomathry.wordpress.com/2016/12/22/first-blog-post/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw an isosceles triangle rectangle with length 1 on real line. Using the Pythagorean Theorem, you can see that its hypotenuse measures $\sqrt{2}$. Now draw a circle with center in the origin of real line and radius $\sqrt{2}$.  Finally the intersection between and positive real line and the circle will be in  the position of $\sqrt{2}$.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The square root of two can not be expressed as a fraction of whole numbers or as a decimal.  It is the classic example of an irrational number.  The real numbers are infinite limits of rationals but the irrationals can not be expressed completely in any finite form.  Geometrically the diagonal of a square with sides of one unit, will be the square root of two units.  The square root can be estimated as about 1.414... but the decimal never ends doesn't repeat cyclically.